# vim is using previous version of vimrc under some circumstances

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

Funny thing is happening to me on `vim`: I made some changes to a user's `~/.vimrc` in order to customize the status line with a simple function (the changes were made on several saves while I refined the code) and now that code loads without any issues if I run `vim FILE` from the command line but for some reason it loads a previous version of `.vimrc` (that is, a previously saved version) when I run `sudo visudo` or run `vim` from the GUI (app menu).

Very strange.

I can spot this because it gives a syntax error within that function due to a missing `let` which I fixed in the final version and loads fine for the user from shell but not for the user when run from the GUI or when using `sudo` where a version of the code with the syntax error is loaded at startup instead.

I tried copying the user's `.vimrc` to `/root` and I ran `grep -rI "functionName" ~` but neither helped.

The funny thing is that, when inside `vim` with a broken status line, if I use `:e $MYVIMRC` it does load the correct one so that I can also use `:source $MYVIMRC` and everything then looks fine (that is, the status line works, and the syntax error is gone).

Any guesses as to why at `vim`startup, in those two situations (and maybe more), uses a previous version?

Comment: The answer by Ingo prompted me to triple-check the function code and it was a matter of another mistake in a chain of if's that was taking turn in running depending on the opened file. It helped a lot to go through the vim log though.

Comment: comment removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hear "outdated configuration", I'd suspect the following:

- broken symlink / forgot to copy user config to root (this is specific to your use case of running under root)
- stored session (`:mksession`) includes old config and is automatically restored (doesn't seem to be the case here)
- environment issue (Vim has several locations and overrides to look for configuration, as outlined by `:help startup`)

I'd check `:scriptnames` in the broken root session first. This should tell which `~/.vimrc` is picked up, and whether any other (alternative) configs are mistakenly loaded, too. If that doesn't offer any clues, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog` (maybe prefixed with `sudo` in your case, so that the problem occurs). After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file, and maybe add comments to the `~/.vimrc` so that you can distinguish the different file versions.